# OpenCV Error: Image step is wrong using EigenFaceRecognizer in JavaCV

Tags: java, opencv, face-recognition, opencv3.0

I am trying to achieve EigenFace Recognition in JavaCV and implementing it through this code:-

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String trainingDir = "C:/Users/user/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Face/testimg";

    IplImage testImage = cvLoadImage("C:/Users/user/Desktop/aa.png");

    File root = new File(trainingDir);

    FilenameFilter pngFilter = new FilenameFilter() {
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            return name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".png");
        }
    };

    File[] imageFiles = root.listFiles(pngFilter);

    MatVector images = new MatVector(imageFiles.length);

    int[] labels = new int[imageFiles.length];

    int counter = 0;
    int label;

    IplImage img;
    IplImage grayImg = null;
    try {
        for (File image : imageFiles) {
            img = cvLoadImage(image.getAbsolutePath(), CV_BGR2GRAY);
            int yer = image.getName().indexOf(".");
            String isim = image.getName().substring(0, yer);

            label = Integer.parseInt(isim);

            images.put(counter, img);

            labels[counter] = label;

            counter++;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    IplImage greyTestImage = IplImage.create(testImage.width(), testImage.height(), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);

   //FaceRecognizer faceRecognizer = createFisherFaceRecognizer();
    FaceRecognizer faceRecognizer = createEigenFaceRecognizer();
    //FaceRecognizer faceRecognizer = createLBPHFaceRecognizer()

    faceRecognizer.train(images, labels);

    cvCvtColor(testImage, greyTestImage, CV_BGR2GRAY);

    int predictedLabel = faceRecognizer.predict(greyTestImage);

    System.out.println("Predicted label: " + predictedLabel);
  }
```

But each time I run it,It gives me an error

> OpenCV Error: Image step is wrong (The matrix is not continuous, thus its number of rows can not be changed) in cv::Mat::reshape, file ........\opencv\modules\core\src\matrix.cpp, line 802
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: ........\opencv\modules\core\src\matrix.cpp:802: error: (-13) The matrix is not continuous, thus its number of rows can not be changed in function cv::Mat::reshape

I have read some where that it happens when Images are not of same size and not a multiple of 8,but i have all the images of same size and grayscaled too.The code i used for saving detected Face is:-

```
    Mat image_roi = new Mat(frame,rect_Crop);
    Imgproc.cvtColor(image_roi, image_roi, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    Size sz = new Size(240,240);
    Imgproc.resize( image_roi, image_roi, sz );
    String filename = "testimg\\" +jTextField1.getText() + ".png";
    System.out.println(String.format("Writing %s", filename));
    Imgcodecs.imwrite(filename, image_roi);
```

It also gives me

> java.lang.NumberFormatException:

for my files don't know why.....???
Please help....!!!!